# How can I access the cities of a country in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce supports country and state select. I tried to use WC_Countries class in woocommerce but i didn't see any related methods. Is it possible or woocommerce doesn't support Cities...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add custom fields to the checkout of WooCommerce.

Heres a full list of fields in the array passed to woocommerce_checkout_fields:

billing

- billing_first_name
- billing_last_name
- billing_company
- billing_address_1
- billing_address_2
- billing_city
- billing_postcode
- billing_country
- billing_state
- billing_email
- billing_phone

shipping

- shipping_first_name
- shipping_last_name
- shipping_company
- shipping_address_1
- shipping_address_2
- shipping_city
- shipping_postcode
- shipping_country
- shipping_state

account

- account_username
- account_password
- account_password-2

order

- order_comments

Each field contains an array of properties:

- type – type of field (text, textarea, password, select)
- label – labelfor the input field
- placeholder – placeholder for the input
- class – class for the input
- required – true or false, whether or not the
  field is require
- clear – true or false, applies a clear fix to the
  field/label
- label_class – class for the label element options – for
  select boxes, array of options (key => value pairs)

[More info](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)